# <HTMLVideoElement> does not play everytime on android

Tags: android, html, angular, video

I'm currently working on an Ionic/Angular app and I have problems with the video on android.
Everything works fine with ios and web browsers it's just Android.

I'll explain briefly how it is supposed to work. (The app is supposed to help with sports exercises)

I have a preview that can be clicked to show the video demo before doing the exercise. When you click on it plays the video, if you click again it pauses the video. Everything works fine for every platform.

Under the preview, you have a button that activates a function to start the video and reset it to 0

And the exercise start.

The function to start when clicking on the button :

```
onClickStartButton() {
    this.isExerciseStarted = true;
    this.exercise.sessionExerciseNumber = this._exerciseIndex;
    this.overviewsService.setExercise(this.exercise);

    if (this.video.nativeElement) {
      (<HTMLVideoElement>this.video.nativeElement).pause();
      (<HTMLVideoElement>this.video.nativeElement).currentTime = 0;
      (<HTMLVideoElement>this.video.nativeElement).play();
      this.isVideoPlaying = false;
    }
}
```

I tried to set a timeout on the if statement to see if the pause() or play() started before the video was fully loaded (i stopped testing after a 3 second timeout) but it doesn't seem to come from there

Here is the HTML of the video being loaded

```
<video class="ion-no-margin" #video 
       *ngIf="exercise?.video" playsinline loop preload="metadata" 
       [ngClass]="{'preview-video': !isExerciseStarted}" tappable (click)="onTapToggleVideo()" 
       [poster]="exercise.thumbnail">
```

I have no idea WHY it does not work just for Android.

Comment: Why you don't try to use native plugin Video player  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player ?

Comment: I'll probably do but it was easier at first to just use html and it worked pretty well before i found this small bug

Comment: Don't forget you're developing a mobile application, not a web, with VideoElement and HTML tags maybe it hurts performance and User experience